# Error loading existing db data into Django (fixtures, postgresql)

Tags: django, django-models

Am trying to load some generated data into Django without disrupting the existing data in the site. What I have:

1. Saved the data as a valid JSON (validated [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator)).
2. The JSON format matches [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#json-1). In previous attempts I also aligned it to [the Django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) *(slightly different field order, the result was the same)*.

Output errors I'm receiving are very generic and not helpful, even with `verbosity=3`.

**The Error Prompt**

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: workoutprogrammes
Running migrations:
  Applying workoutprogrammes.0005_auto_20220415_2021...Loading '/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/src/workoutprogrammes/fixtures/datafile_2' fixtures...
Checking '/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/src/workoutprogrammes/fixtures' for fixtures...
Installing json fixture 'datafile_2' from '/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/src/workoutprogrammes/fixtures'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 70, in Deserializer
    yield from PythonDeserializer(objects, **options)
  File "/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 93, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
KeyError: 'model'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:... text continues on...
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 74, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/Robert/Desktop/Projects/Powerlifts/src/workoutprogrammes/fixtures/datafile_2.json':
```

**auto_2022_migration.py file:**

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.core.management import call_command
def db_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    call_command('loaddata', '/filename.json', verbosity=3)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):   
    dependencies = [('workoutprogrammes', '0004_extable_delete_ex_table'),]

    operations = [migrations.RunPython(db_migration),]
```

**JSON file extract** *(start... end)*

*NB: all my PKs are UUIDs generated from postgresql*

```
[{"pk":"af82d5f4-2814-4d52-b2b1-6add6cf18d3c","model":"workoutprogrammes.ex_table","fields":{"exercise_name":"Cable Alternating Front Raise","utility":"Auxiliary","mechanics":"Isolated","force":"Push","levator_scapulae":"Stabilisers",..."obliques":"Stabilisers","psoas_major":""}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original error was. I suspect it had to do with either editing the table/schema using psql separately from Django, OR using the somewhat outdated `uuid-ossp` package instead of `pgcrypto` package (native to Djagno via `CryptoExtension()`). I was never able to confirm. I did however manage to get it working by:

1. Deleting the table (schema, data) using psql and the app using Django. Creating a new app in Django.
2. Load the prev model data into this `new_app/models.py`. Make new migration file, first updating the `CryptoExtension()` operation before committing the migration.
3. Create Fixtures directory and relevant file ([per Django specs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures), validated JSON [online](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator).
4. Validate my UUIDs [online](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/1000330_UUID_GUID_Validator.html#Result)
5. Load the fixture data into the app. `python3 manage.py loaddata /path/to/data/file_name.json`